# ES6 : create DOM object and get access

Tags: jquery, dom, ecmascript-6

I'm trying to create an DOM object with ES6 class, but I block when I need to change my instance.

```
class Layer{
    constructor(layerIndex){
        this._layerId = "layer_"+layerIndex;
        this.layer = $('<div id="'+this._layerId+'">');
        this.createLayerDiv();
    }
    getDOMContent(){
        return jQuery('<div />').append(this.layer.eq(0).clone()).html();
    }
    createLayerDiv(){
        var content = '<div class="row">text</div>';
        this.layer.append(content);
        this.layer.addClass("oldClass");
    }
    addClass(class){
        this.layer.addClass(class);
    }
}

var layer = new Layer(0);
$("body").append(layer.getDOMContent());
layer.addClass("newClass");
```

"newClass" isn't added to my DOM object.
Any idea ? I suppose there is something like pointer or instance issue, but I can't find a solution.

Thanks a lot you for your help !
vanessa

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`getDOMContent` return a **string** (the result of calling `html` on a div you create and add a **clone** of your layer to). So naturally calling `addClass` on `layer` *after* adding that string to the DOM won't make any difference in what you added to the DOM, because A) You added a string, and B) It was a string created by serializing a *clone* of your layer.

You probably want to either add the class first, or return your actual element (or jQuery object) from `getDOMContent`, not a string. But youll need to change more than just that, since you're cloning as well.

Comment: Yes you're completely right, thanks for your answer. I finally work with objects only and don't use anymore the clone.html() trick.